# Find out which query, process generate oracle archive log

Tags: oracle

Our database is shared between few teams. Since a few day ago, our database generate a lots of archive log, making our server run out of space. There a day with over 60gb, ~1gb each file each 30minute.

I have asked other team if they have any process which make a lot of change to database but they all denied.

So i want to check the root cause of this, find out which user, table, process or query which generated these log. Any1 know a way to check it?